# Make a cron like schedule

Tags: php, mysql, cron

My webhost doesn't have cron in it so I cannot set up cron jobs.
There is a certain php script in my website that should be ran every 24 hours to write daily logs etc.

I tried looking for external schedulers but I don't trust them.

How can I do such thing without cron? 
I thought I maybe could use a mysql server and have an event or something?

I do **NOT** want it to rely on when a user uses my website due to the exact daily timing that I need.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: sadly thats not an option for me right now..

Comment: should i trust this? https://www.setcronjob.com/

Answer (score 0):

From a different host, set up a cronjob that does a `wget` of a page on your web-site. When that page is loaded, it does your script.